# Increase Azure blob block upload limit from 32 MB

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a contents to azure blob and the size is over 32MB. The c# code snippet below:

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
blob.UploadFromByteArray(contents, 0, contents.Length, AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition(), options:writeOptions);
```

Everytime the blob is over 32MB, the above raises an exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

As per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691964.aspx)

> When a block blob upload is larger than the value in this property,
>   storage clients break the file into blocks.

Should there be a separate line of code to enable this.

Comment: I tried your code without the writeOptions parameter and it works fine with a file of 35MB.

Comment: I was also able to upload a 35 MB byte array to a block blob without error. The client library handles the work of uploading your data as blocks when you use this method; there's nothing else you need to do.

Comment: One problem with your code: there's no overload for UploadFromByteArray that takes this combination of arguments, so this code shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Storage clients default to a 32 MB maximum single block upload. When a block blob upload is larger than the value in `SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes` property, storage clients break the file into blocks.

As Tamra said, the storage client handles the work of breaking the file into blocks. Here is my tests for you to have a better understanding of it.

**Code Sample**

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
var writeOptions = new BlobRequestOptions()
{
    SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes = 50 * 1024 * 1024, //maximum for 64MB,32MB by default          
};
blob.UploadFromByteArray(contents, 0, contents.Length, AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition(), options: writeOptions);
```

**Scenario**

1. If you are writing a block blob that is no more than the `SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes` property in size, you could upload it in its entirety with a single write operation.

   You could understand it by capturing the Network Package via Fiddler when you invoke the `UploadFromByteArray` method.

   [image]
2. When a block blob upload is larger than the value in `SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes` property in size, storage clients break the file into blocks automatically.

   I upload a blob which size is nearly 90MB, then you could find the difference as follows:

   [image]

   Upon the snapshot, you could find that storage clients break the file into blocks with 4MB in size and upload the blocks simultaneously.

> Every time the blob is over 32MB, the above raises an exception

You could try to set the `SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes` property or capture the Network Package when you invoke the `UploadFromByteArray` method to find the detailed error.